# How is the word "elated" used?

Tags: word-usage, difference

I found 'elated' means 'excited'.  I had known and used a lot about 'excited', but I am not familiar with 'elated'.  Can it be used in the same way as 'I was elated by that news'?  Is there any difference in its connotation compared with 'excited'?

Comment: http://www.onelook.com/?ls=b&w=elated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Elated* necessarily implies that you're happy- unreservedly happy. Happiness is the dominant component of your excitement. You might be excited for the first day of school, but if you're nervous at the same time, you're probably not elated.

Comment: "In spite of my anxiety about Felicity, I felt rather elated."--Holt, Victoria The Road to Paradise Island (per [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/elated))